# Find the source from which a module is installed

Tags: powershell

How can I find the PSRepository or other source from which a PowerShell module is installed?

```
PS C:\src> Get-Command Add-ExcelName

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Add-ExcelName                                      7.1.1      ImportExcel

PS C:\src> Get-Module ImportExcel

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     7.1.1      ImportExcel                         {Add-ConditionalFormatting, Add-ExcelChart, Add-ExcelDataValidationRule, Add-ExcelName...
```

This does not reveal the source from which it is installed.

```
Get-Command Add-ExcelName | Format-List *
Get-Module ImportExcel | Format-List *
```

What would tell me that this is installed from PSGallery?

```
PS C:\src> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
5.1.17763.1490
```

Comment: You want `Get-InstalledModule`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, many thanks. It you will post it as an answer, I will select it.